# How to perform JSR223 assertion test on a JSON array which is the value of a key in JMeter?

Tags: json, jmeter, assertion, web-api-testing, jsr223

I want to perform an assertion test on a JSON array represented as follows in JMeter:

```
{
  "item": [
    {
      "id": "cx34ty1",
      "name": "xyzitem",
      "isSerialNoRequired": false,
      "itemProps": {
        "type": "readonly",
        "count": 10
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I know that it is possible to assert for the presence of a key using JSR223 assertion, for eg. "item" in this case using:

```
if (!jsonResponse.keySet().containsAll(["item"])) {
          failureMessage += "The json config element has wrong structure.\n\n";
```

What should I do if I want to assert for the presence of a key within the array, or eg. "id" or "itemProps"? Also, given that JSON Assertion is resource intensive, I don't want to use it since I also want to check for multiple keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same approach, like:

```
def jsonResponse = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

if (!jsonResponse.keySet().contains('item')) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('"item" element was not found')
}

if (!jsonResponse.item.get(0).keySet().contains('id') || !jsonResponse.item.get(0).keySet().contains('itemProps')) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('"id" or "itemProps" element was not found')
}
```

However you could come up with a better solution, for example use [JSON Schema Validator](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema) library, if you download the .jar and put it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you will be able to test JSON response against pre-defined [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) and in case of mismatch (missing mandatory key or wrong data type of value) you will be notified.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)